# Link rendered correctly in edit mode, but not in normal viewing

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

I have just noticed this issue, w.r.t the first link in the first line:

In edit mode, the URL is resolved to the question title:

> [image: URL resolved in Edit mode]

Then after hitting save:

> [image: URL not resolved]

The URL is no longer resolved to the title of the question.

This is [the post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7763/why-do-we-generally-prefer-dh-parameters-over-other-kinematic-representations-of/7851#7851) in question.

In order to get it to render correctly in normal view mode I had to do the usual:

```
[What are the advantages of using the Denavit-Hartenberg representation?][1]

  [1]: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-the-denavit-hartenberg-representation
```

Using Opera 37.0 on OSX 10.8.5

Comment: It could be because link titles are only supposed to be highlighted if they are HTTPS, and the editor preview hasn't been updated to handle that.

Comment: As yes! Well spotted. Works as expected when https is used. It was an old fashioned http link copied from a comment to the question, above. Thank you :-)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog that looks like the real answer, mind to post it as an answer? /cc Greenonline :)

Comment: @Somewhat I'd rather edit this into a bug, which reports that the editor preview should no longer be converting HTTP internal links to titles.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog -  Please feel fee to make any edits that you deem necessary. I thought about changing the title to refer to http URLs not being resolved correctly.