# Link in quotes rendered as title in edit preview mode but as URL in the rendered post

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

It looks like links to questions within quotes are being rendered with the question title in the edit mode preview, but as a URL in normal viewing.

---

Given the following question Markdown:

```markdown
Testing some link formatting:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

"https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work"
```

The following images show the difference in rendering between edit mode & view mode:

### Question view:

> [image]

### Edit preview:

> [image]

### Current live rendering:

*(Actual live rendering, not an image. This can be used to view the current behavior, including the discrepancy.)*

> Testing some link formatting:
>
> [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)
>
> "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work"

---

There are other past issues about link rendering discrepancies, but none of them seem to be quite this issue:

- [Link rendered correctly in edit mode, but not in normal viewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315034/link-rendered-correctly-in-edit-mode-but-not-in-normal-viewing)
- [Link works in edit view, but not in the rendered post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244894/link-works-in-edit-view-but-not-in-the-rendered-post)
- [Link working in preview but not on post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175448/link-working-in-preview-but-not-on-post)
- [Link formatting broken when it renders correctly in preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311571/link-formatting-broken-when-it-renders-correctly-in-preview)

Comment: The preview and the actual posts use different renderers. It's a known fact the the server renderer only recognises URL's when they are enclosed in spaces.

Comment: It appears that I was mistaken. Double quotes at the start of the link break the URL, not at the end. You can see in your sandbox answer, I tested there.

Comment: The referenced sandbox answer, for those playing along at home: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/357576#357576